# Model attribute changing on find and save in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in Rails, User. Everytime I refer to him (for example, `find_by_name("NAME")` in `script/console`), its field/attribute `last_login` changes to the current time.

Here's my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # ACCOUNT INFORATION VALIDATION
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    validates_length_of :name, :in => 4..16
    validates_format_of :name, :with => /^\w+$/i, :message => "can only contain letters, numbers and underlines."
    validates_presence_of :password
    validates_length_of :password, :in => 16..42, :message => "must be between 6 and 32 characters." #10 digits salt included
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i

    # VALIDATES ENERGY AND HP
    before_save :check_attributes

    def after_find
        check_attributes(true)
    end

    def check_attributes(save=false)

        # HP
        if self.damage > 0 and self.last_hp_recovery.nil?
            self.last_hp_recovery=Time.now
        end

        while !self.last_hp_recovery.nil? and  self.last_hp_recovery<hp_recovery_time.minutes.ago
            self.damage-=1
            if self.damage == 0
                self.last_hp_recovery = nil
            else
                self.last_hp_recovery+=hp_recovery_time.minutes
            end
        end

        # ENERGY
        if self.energy_used > 0 and self.last_energy_recovery.nil?
            self.last_energy_recovery=Time.now
        end

        while !self.last_energy_recovery.nil? and  self.last_energy_recovery<energy_recovery_time.minutes.ago
            self.energy_used-=1
            if self.energy_used == 0
                self.last_energy_recovery = nil
            else
                self.last_energy_recovery+=energy_recovery_time.minutes
            end
        end

        self.save if save
    end


    def energy_recovery_time
        1
    end

    def hp_recovery_time
        1
    end

    # ATRIBUTES
    def hp
        @hp=max_hp-self.damage
    end

    def max_hp
        @max_hp=self.base_max_hp+race_hp_bonus
    end

    def energy
        @energy=max_energy-self.energy_used
    end

    def max_energy
        @max_energy=self.base_max_energy+race_energy_bonus
    end

    def attack
        @attack=self.base_attack+race_attack_bonus
    end

    def defense
        @defense=self.base_defense+race_defense_bonus
    end

    def agility
        @agility=self.base_agility+race_agility_bonus
    end

    # OTHER FUNCTIONS
    def generate_salt
        self.salt=""
        10.times do
            self.salt+=rand(10).to_s
        end
    end

    private
    # RACE FUNCTIONS
    def race_hp_bonus

        case self.race
        when 0

            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 100
            end

        when 1
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 110
            end

        when 2
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 90
            end
        end

        return 0

    end 

    def race_energy_bonus

        case self.race
        when 0

            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 100
            end

        when 1
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 110
            end

        when 2
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 90
            end
        end

        return 0

    end

    def race_attack_bonus

        case self.race
        when 0

            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 10
            end

        when 1
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 11
            end

        when 2
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 9
            end
        end

        return 0

    end 

    def race_defense_bonus

        case self.race
        when 0

            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 10
            end

        when 1
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 11
            end

        when 2
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 9
            end
        end

        return 0

    end 

    def race_agility_bonus

        case self.race
        when 0

            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 10
            end

        when 1
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 11
            end

        when 2
            case self.level
            when 1..5
                return 9
            end
        end

        return 0

    end 

end
```

Any ideas why and how to prevent?

Thank you very much,
Gabriel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my computer (restarting the server didn't work) and now it's ok... *strange...*